# In java web start where does the jar file get downloaded to?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

As per Java web start where does the jar file get downloaded on a client machine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case of a Windows machine, you could go to the control panel and click on Java Control Panel to find the location of the Java Cache.
In my case it shows: C:\Documents and Settings\user1\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache

Comment: The Java Control Panel is available on Linux & Solaris as well. On GNOME it can usually be found under System->Preferences->Java

Comment: Default seems to be C:\Users\{user}\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache

Answer (score 4):

On Mac

```
/Users/username/Library/Caches/Java/cache/
```

Just for fun:
I deployed a small game and found its jar file in

```
/Users/username/Library/Caches/Java/cache/6.0/42/1d3d9f6a-640bd5ed
```

The .jar was removed, if you want to run or decompile it, rename it with `.jar`

**UPDATE (OS X El Capitan)**

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/cache
```

Comment: There is no `Java` folder in my `Caches` folder (running macOS Sierra)

Answer (score 3):

In case of a Linux machine, I have it on :

> /home/bakkal/.java/deployment/cache/

where /home/bakkal is just my personal home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the location on windows has changed. It was different in java 6 (compared to java 5).

Comment: Where is that? This does not answer the question